# findAllByPropertyInList results in wrong result, JOIN related or hibernate Distinct/paging problem?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, distinct

I have some strange results of findAllByPropertyInList() and think
this is a bug in grails. See [1], the result is not what I expect it
to be and what other queries say.
Could it be that some kind of JOIN blows up the result, than
max-property is executed and afterwards DISTINCT decreases the number
of results again?

Or does this have to do with Hibernate not being able to use DISTINCT and pagination proerties in one query?

thx Sebastian

[1]

```
def criteria = Foo.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.listDistinct() {
 ...
}
results.id.unique().size()
==>34
results.topic.unique().size() // some of the topics are duplicate
==>25
def more = Foo.findAll([max:20, offset:0]).size()
==>20
def more = Foo.getAll(results.id).size()
==>34
def more = Foo.findAllByTopicInList(results.topic, [max:20, offset:0]).size()
==> 7  // expected 25
def more = Foo.findAllByIdInList(results.id, [max:20, offset:0]).size()
==> 7  // expected 34

class Foo {
  String topic
  SubCategory subCategory
  List<Article> articles
  WritingStyle writingStyle
  SortedSet<Keyword> keywords = []as SortedSet
  SortedSet<String> linkTexts = []as SortedSet
  ArticleType articleType = ArticleType.FreestyleArticle

  static belongsTo = [project: Project]
  static hasMany = [articles:Article, keywords: Keyword, linkTexts: String]

  static constraints = {
    topic(blank: false, size: 1..200)
    subCategory(nullable: false)
    writingStyle(nullable: true)
    articles nullable:true
  }

  static mapping = {
    writingStyle fetch: 'join'
    subCategory fetch: 'join'
    keywords cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    keywords fetch: 'join'
    linkTexts cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
  }
}
```

Comment: I would expect the last two results to be 20, because you set the max param. Without the max, I would expect 34 in both cases.

Comment: probably you have associations in your domain model. Can you show us Foo? I guess you have defined to `fetch` those eager and not lazy. This will result in having one result item per association.

Comment: @user852518 yes your right, but still some results are missing

Comment: @crudolf: I added the Foo Domain, but there is only fetch: 'join', no eager, no lazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch the fetch mode to `lazy`, it will work. This is kind of "known" behaviour of "max" in combination with join/eager fetch mode. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5469